# Centering text/pictures in HTML with markdown and pandoc

Tags: markdown, pandoc, hakyll

I am trying to write a post with [`hakyll`](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/) in `markdown` via `pandoc`.

I successfully added some pictures, tables and code blocks with `markdown`. However, I would like to center my pictures and some text paragraph.

**Is it possible to center text and pictures with `pandoc` and the `markdown` markup language?**

Comment: For those in the unknown, [`hakyll` produces static web sites](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/) using `pandoc`. Hence, the `pandoc` output is `html`. This was originally not specified by the OP in his question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of markdown as a nicer syntax for HTML – it's only the content, no styling. (Centering would be styling.) You cannot center text in HTML either. But you can add classes, then style them with CSS (in your Hakyll theme).

Pandoc markdown currently supports attributes on images:

```
![](img.jpg){.myClass}
```

but not paragraphs, however you can wrap stuff in [divs](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#divs-and-spans):

```
# my markdown header

::: {.myClass}

one paragraph

second paragraph, **strong**

:::
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more? Is (must?) the header (be) a separate file from the markdown file? How is it included in the markdown file?

Comment: "Centering would be styling" -- so is bold, italics, underline, ordered/unordered lists, etc. ...

Comment: @theMayer: ‘italics’ might be styling, but ‘emphasize’ is semantic. So are lists.